# How to return two separate arrays of keys and values

Tags: ruby, arrays

Please explain how this piece of code can return two arrays.

```
def keysAndValues(data)
  [data.keys, data.values]
end
```

Comment: What is passed as `data`? Since you have not explained it, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Oh so sorry, Data is particularly a Hash here

Answer (score 1):

`keysAndValues` method does return a single array (of two arrays inside of it), but its output can be interpreted as two arrays. Let me explain:

```
single_array = ["hello", "world"]
puts single_array # => ["hello", "world"]
first_element, second_element = single_array
puts first_element # => "hello"
puts second_element # => "world"
```

The reason this notation is possible is the implementation of Ruby's assignment (`=`) operator. Thus, calling `a, b = keysAndValues(data)` makes both variables `a` and `b` filled. But beware, although the outcome technically makes sense this might be unexpected in some situations:

```
first, second = 1 # first is 1, second is nil
```

There are also some other uses for multiple assignment, consider the following case:

```
a, b, *c = [1, 2, 3, 4] # note the asterisk symbol here
puts a # => 1
puts b # => 2
puts c # => [3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby supports parallel assignment. This is a simple example:

```
foo, bar = 1, 2
foo # => 1
bar # => 2
```

Your method is returning two values inside an array:

```
keys_and_values(
  {
    a: 1,                    
    b: 2                     
  }                          
).size # => 2
```

which are assigned via `=` to the two values on the left side of the equation. The values in the array are references to where the `keys` and `values` sub-arrays are located:

```
foo, bar = keys_and_values(
  {
    a: 1,                    
    b: 2                     
  }                          
)

foo.object_id  # => 70159936091440
bar.object_id  # => 70159936091420
```

Ruby isn't unique with supporting parallel assignment; It is used in other languages too. Any decent Ruby manual will talk about this. It's good to understand because the assignment to variables, or passing multiple parameters to methods is something you'll encounter repeatedly in Ruby. Do [a search](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+parallel+assignment) for more information.

Also, in Ruby we don't name methods using camelCase, such as "keysAndValues". Instead we use snake_case: `keys_and_values`.

Comment: "list assignment" not "parallel"

Comment: It's parallel, list, depending on the languages you've used before. Look at the results of the search; Obviously people use both.